# A Poisson Question

Tags: poisson-distribution

[IB Poisson Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF56Q.png)

> A ferry carries cars across a river. There is a fixed time of $T$ minutes between crossings.
>   The arrival of cars at the crossing can be assumed to follow a Poisson distribution with
>   a mean of one car every four minutes. Let $X$ denote the number of cars that arrive
>   in $T$ minutes.
>
> **(a)** Find $T$ , to the nearest minute, if $P(X ≤ 3) = 0.6$. [3 marks]
>
> It is now decided that the time between crossings, $T$ , will be $10$ minutes. The ferry can
>   carry a maximum of three cars on each trip.
>
> **(b)** One day all the cars waiting at $13:00$ get on the ferry. Find the probability that
>   all the cars that arrive in the next $20$ minutes will get on either the $13:10$ or the
>   $13:20$ ferry. [4 marks]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried to solve the problem? It helps us know **exactly** where you are stuck, so we can help in the best way possible (We then don't repeat information you already know).

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints:**

---

Note that the probability mass function for:
$$X\sim \operatorname*{Po}(\lambda)$$
Is given by:
$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\cdot \lambda^x}{x!}$$

---

For **(a)**, note that there is a mean of $1$ car every $4$ minutes. Therefore, the distribution to consider is:
$$X\sim \operatorname*{Po}\left(\frac{1}{4}T\right)$$
Can you now find the value of $T$ from $P(X\leq 3)=0.6$?

---

For **(b)**, let $X_1$ and $X_2$ denote the number of cars which arrive in the first $10$ minutes and second period respectively. They must each follow a distribution of:
$$X_1\sim \operatorname*{Po}(2.5)$$
$$X_2\sim \operatorname*{Po}(2.5)$$
Now, try finding all the possibilities and add them up to obtain the desired probability.